# Get file type based on extension vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My need is to display default images for each group based on file type for the uploaded images. That is

I am having `file Groups` as

- **picture** for `{".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif", ".tif"}`
- **document** for `{".doc", ".docx", ".txt", ".htm", ".html", ".xml", ".xaml", ".css"}`
- **excel** for `{".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlt", ".xla"}`
- **pdf** for `".pdf"`
- **zip** for `{".7z", ".APK", ".BAT", ".rar", ".dll", ".jar", ".zip"}`

If the input extension is **".xls"** then i need the output as `"excel"`

I had tried with  `Select Case`

```
  Select Case search
        Case ".docx"
            extensionType = "document"
        Case ".doc"
            extensionType = "document"
        Case ".txt"
            extensionType = "document"
         ---------
    End Select
```

But code is very lengthy how can i short this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet) concept for this kind of operation: consider the following code

```
Private Sub getfileType_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles getfileType.Click
    Dim array As String()
    Dim extensionType As String
    Dim dics As New Dictionary(Of String, String()) From { _
    {"picture", New String() {".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif", ".tif"}}, _
    {"document", New String() {".doc", ".docx", ".txt", ".htm", ".html", ".xml", ".xaml", ".css"}}, _
    {"excel", New String() {".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlt", ".xla"}}, _
    {"pdf", New String() {".pdf"}}, _
    {"zip", New String() {".7z", ".APK", ".BAT", ".rar", ".dll", ".jar", ".zip"}}, _
    {"ppt", New String() {".ppt", ".pos", ".pps"}}}
    Dim pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String())
    For Each pair In dics
        If attachmentType(pair.Key, pair.Value, ".APK") = True Then
            extensionType = pair.Key
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox("File Type is :" & extensionType)
End Sub

Public Function attachmentType(ByVal input As String, ByVal array() As String, ByVal search As String) As Boolean
    Dim temp As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
        If array(i) = search Then temp = 1
    Next
    If temp = 1 Then
        attachmentType = True
    Else
        attachmentType = False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple CASE condition per single line:

```
Select Case search
    Case ".doc", ".docx", ".txt"
        extensionType = "document"
    Case ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp"
        extensionType = "picture"
End Select
```

Or you can use dict as well, but with extension as a key:

```
Dim map As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
map.Add(".doc", "document")
map.Add(".docx", "document")
map.Add(".jpg", "picture")
map.Add(".png", "picture")
Console.WriteLine(map(".docx"))
```